# Define the highest time unit of date difference that has a whole number

Tags: java, date, java-time, duration, localdate

I have 2 dates:

```
LocalDate date1 = LocalDate.now().minusDays(40);
LocalDate date2 = LocalDate.now();
```

I want to figure out what is the biggest time unit I can pick to define the difference between the 2 (out of days, months, years), and to get its number.
The perfect solution for me, I think, would been if `Duration` of `java.time` api had also `toMonthsPart` and `toYearsPart` as it has `toDaysPart`. This way I could do this:

```
Duration dif = Duration.between(date1, date2);

long daysPart = dif.toDaysPart();
if (daysPart > 0) {
    return ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(date1, date2);
}

long monthPart = dif.getMonthsPart();
if (monthPart > 0) {
    return ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(date1, date2);
}

long yearPart = dif.getYearsPart();
if (yearPart > 0) {
    return ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(date1, date2);
}

throw new Exception("no difference");
```

But there is no such methods in the API.
Is there another package can provide this functionality, or do you know of different approach to achieve my goal?

Comment: This question meets the [requirements of a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I don't see any reason for the close vote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### TL;DR

Use [`Period`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Period.html) instead of [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html).

**Demo**:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Period;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
        LocalDate fortyDaysAgo = today.minusDays(40);
        Period period = Period.between(fortyDaysAgo, today);
        System.out.println(period);
        System.out.printf("%d year(s) %d month(s) %d day(s)%n", period.getYears(), period.getMonths(),
                period.getDays());
    }
}
```

**Output from a sample run:**

```
P1M9D
0 year(s) 1 month(s) 9 day(s)
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/XIrUya)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.